# Ajax with mysql and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have checkboxes on my page for which I would like to send their state to the database via ajax. 
Everything works with SELECT and OPTIONS, but I don't know to do the same things with several checkboxes and how to get the value from them.

The data retrived only for one checkbox?when I change checkbox it doen't work

Any ideas?

my code looks like this->

```js
$('.item').on('click', function() {

  var name = $('.item').val();
  $.post('load.php', {
    name: name
  }, function(data) {
    $('#name-data').html(data);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="item">что то</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="item">Шорты</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="item">Классическая</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".checkbox").on("change", ".item", function() {
    alert('event');
    if (this.checked) {
      alert('post');
      $.post('load.php', {
        name: name
      }, function(data) {
        $('#name-data').html(data);
      });

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="item">что то</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="item">Шорты</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="item">Классическая</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**online demo link**](https://jsfiddle.net/urahkb6c/1/)